# Внести значения в базу данных при изменении значений в таблице

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день, я только начинаю изучать php/ javascript.

1) Хочу из базы вывести значения в таблицу такого типа

```
Фио     Математика Физика           Химия 
иванов      5         2               н 
петров      н         3               4
```

2)И если пользователь меняет оценку, что б значения улетали в базу.

Т.е., скажем, `Иванов idStudenta=1,Математика idDisciplini=222`. и на основании этого отправить запрос на изменение. Ну хотя бы общий алгоритм, а в базе по таблицам уже раскидаю как-то.

Comment: Вообще-то у вас тут два вопроса: вывести из базы, ит отправить в базу :) Вывести, думаю, совсем не сложно. А вот отправить в базу... В общих чертах: Вам нужно воспользоваться ajax. На странице есть форма, которую пользователь меняет. При изменении данных в форме вы должны послать на определенный php файл содержимое формы, оформленное как `&name1=value1&name1=value1`. PHP файл получает данные и раскидывает по таблицам. Так в общих чертах рабобтает ajax.

Comment: Спасибо. Это уже решено. Было ещё в 2014- тогда не знал, как делать.